# Django: Group dates by Year

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

im trying to create like a timeline from a model's created field but i can't find a clean way to do it. The idea is to return to the frontend ( DRF ) a list of years with their dates inside.
So let's say that i have this model:

```
class ProductModel(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
  created = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today, blank=True)
```

Let's say that 6 products have been created ( 3 of them from 2021 and 3 from 2022). So i would like to return something like this:

```
"timeline": {

    "2021": [
        ...,
        "2021-12-1",
        "2021-11-1",
        "2021-10-1",
    ],
    "2022": [
        ...,
        "2022-03-1",
        "2022-02-1",
        "2022-01-1",
    ],
}
```

The idea it's only to return dates of created products and nothing else. But i don't now how to group the dates by years. I've tried with annotate and values but not the result that i need.
I understand that on the serializer part i would have to use serializers.ListField() in order to be able to pass lists to it.

Any suggestion im all ears. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

You used key:pair inside a list structure, so I will just assume its wrong and you meant a dictionary.

For that output, one possible solution:

serializers.py

```
class TimeLineSerializer(serializers.Serializer):

    timeline = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_timeline(self, obj):
        data = {}
        dates = obj.values('created__year').distinct()
        for date in dates:
            data[date['created__year']] = obj.filter(created__year=date['created__year']).values_list('created', flat=True)

        return data
```

views.py:

```
class TimeLineListAPIView(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        qs = ProductModel.objects.all()
        serializer = TimeLineSerializer(qs)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

output:

```
{
    "timeline": {
        "2021": [
            "2021-12-20",
            "2021-12-21",
            "2021-12-22"
        ],
        "2022": [
            "2022-12-20",
            "2022-12-21",
            "2022-12-23"
        ]
    }
}
```

Of course, there is possibly a cleaner solution that I don't know of.

Comment: Thanks Niko! i edited the example for the "inside a list structure" error. I ended up doing something similar in the views.py file. Correct me if im wrong, but i think that doing all the work in serializers.py will hit the database a lot of time within the "get_timeline" function with the ProductModel.objects.all() and ProductModel.objects.filter() queries. I'll leave what a did just above

Comment: You are right, because  I am wrongly using queries to fetch the data and not using the data passed into the serializer and filtering it like a subquery. I  will update the answer, thanks for the note @Emmanuel

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's the best solution but i've created a generic get_timeline function that goes like this ( thanks to @Niko for the inspiration):

```
def get_timeline(model_queryset, lookup_field):
    '''
    get timeline function will return a dictionary of dates grouping by years.
    '''
    timeline = {}
    for item in model_queryset:
        if hasattr(item, lookup_field):
            date = getattr(item, lookup_field)
            filters = { f'{ lookup_field }__year': date.year }
            timeline[date.year] = model_queryset.filter(**filters).values_list(lookup_field, flat=True)
        else:
            raise ValidationError(f'Object "{ item }" does not have "{ lookup_field }" attribute')
    return timeline
```

In views.py:

```
queryset =  ProductModel.objects.order_by('-created')
timeline = get_timeline(queryset, 'created')
```

And the output:

```
"timeline": {
    "2021": [
        "2021-12-1",
        "2021-11-1",
        "2021-10-1",
    ],
    "2022": [
        "2022-03-1",
        "2022-02-1",
        "2022-01-1",
    ],
},
```

This function will be call in the views.py file passing ProductModel objects as "model_queryset" and "created" as "lookup_field".

Hope that is a clean solution.